# I can apply tasseled Cap transformation in surface reflectance (not ToA)?

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, digital-image-processing, reflectance

I can not understand if I should adjust the Tasseled Cap index with the surface reflectance values or the Top of Atmosphere

Comment: For deriving TC, depending on the sensor, it should be DN (eg., TM5) or at-sensor reflectance eg., ETM7, OLI) and never TOA. I have no idea what you mean by adjusting TC, you need to provide more details and a citation. Please, also read the faq on asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found these Tasseled Cap coefficients for use with Landsat Surface reflectance data.
Please refer to the source article for applicability to your work.
http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0147121
[image]